# Convert byte[] to single

Tags: c#, .net

Problem:

I am trying to convert a `byte[]` to a `single`.  I've tried using `BitConverter.ToSingle()` and it doesn't give the desired result.

The Content of the Array is:

> 0
>   0
>   0
>   100

The desired output is `100`;  I know an Int would work for this but I just choose that number for easy debugging.  I have also tried moving the 100 into every possible position in the array, with no luck.

My output always looks like `9.3345534545E`
or something similar with different digits. 
Any Ideas?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: A single with value 100 is represented as [0, 0, 200, 66]. It's floating point, so it makes sense for it to look different than what you need. Can't you convert to int and then to single?

Answer (score 5):

IEE-754 types (`Single` and `Double` - `float` and `double` in C#) do not have a trivial binary representation so `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x64` does not represent the value of `0x64` (100 in decimal).

The actual raw, binary representation of IEEE-754 values is rather complicated and setting them and performing the conversion from integer to IEE-754 really isn't worth the effort (unless it's a learning exercise). It's best to let the library/platform or even the processor do it for you:

Because your value is an integer value, you need to convert it into `Int32` first, and then use the `Convert` class (or a simple compiler cast which will perform the type conversion under-the-hood).

```
Int32 val = BitConverter.ToInt32( yourArray ); // assuming it's little-endian
Single s1 = (Single)val;
Single s2 = Convert.ToSingle( val );
```

Comment: Why not BitConverter.ToSingle?

Comment: @ClassicThunder because `BitConverter.ToSingle` requires an input array that already contains an IEE-754-formatted number, whereas the OP's array contains an integer value.