# Read Binary File Using Reflection of Target Class

Tags: c#, reflection, binaryfiles

New to c# and looking for help on reading a binary file (generated by a non windows machine) into one of several possible classes...

**The problem:**
The binary files all start with a generic header, which I can read in with no problems. The header tells me which version of data follows. I read this and then create an object based on this information.
I then use reflection to get the field info of this object and understand what I'm reading next. Then read in the appropriate number of bytes, and here is the problem. I would then populate the field with the data. I've written the following...

**The Code:**

```
        Type type = myData.GetType();
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static;
        FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(flags);
        int readSize;
        int readNumber;
        foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
        {
            if (field.FieldType.IsArray)
            {
                Array myArray = (Array)field.GetValue(myData);
                readSize = Marshal.SizeOf(myArray.GetType().GetElementType());
                readNumber = myArray.Rank * myArray.GetLength(myArray.Rank);
                field.SetValue(myData, br.ReadBytes(readSize*readNumber));
            }
            else
            {
                readSize = Marshal.SizeOf(field.FieldType);
                if (readSize > 0)
                {
                    field.SetValue(myData, br.ReadBytes(readSize)); // FAILS HERE
                }
            }
        }
```

When I run this, it falls over at the point indicated with:
`System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type 'System.Byte[]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Single'.'`

Further to this, the binary data can and does contain two dimensional C style arrays, but don't want to use unsafe to crowbar in a solution.

**Possible Solutions...**

I understand why I'm getting this error, thanks to [Convert byte[] to single [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317367/convert-byte-to-single)

But I can't keep switching based on system Type information (System.Single etc...), as covering a reasonable number of possibilities would be huge, and worth avoiding after reading some other good stuff here on the stack.

I also want to avoid Marshalling my target classes, as that would require a lot work creating them. And then, whenever the binary structures change (new firmware on the non windows system) I would have to create a new set again, making the whole thing slightly unmanageable.

Any suggestions, or possible other solutions!?

Comment: what is the type of `br` variable ?

Comment: br is the BinaryReader

Comment: Did you take a look at [binary serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization) ?

Comment: `BinaryReader` is intended for use with `BinaryWriter` - it is *not* intended for decoding ad-hoc protocols; if you need to process arbitrary data, then honestly: a raw `Stream` or pipeline is a better idea; as for loading C-style data: that is very easy if the types are `struct` and don't have any references, i.e. would satisfy the `unmanaged` constraint: does that apply here? if so: `MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, YourType>(theBytes)[0]` (assuming you only want one)

Comment: @SteveB that doesn't apply in the case of interop data, and even when it does apply: *don't use it* - it is considered deprecated and actively dangerous

Comment: Only a quick skim, as the binary file is not a .net output. It comes from a CodeSys controller. However, I'll definitely give it more time now. Thanks @Steve B.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, Thanks. The issue with a struct in c# is it doesn't allow 2d Arrays. In short I have what is essentially a C style binary file that I need to populate a class with. The future management issues are making me look for a solution that provides a quick implementation of the next version of the binary files.

Comment: @VariableSquid and what is the size of the 2d array? fixed? or is the length prefixed? for reasonable sized data, fixed buffers may help (which you *can* do inside a struct); alternatively, you can decode the data manually, dealing with the array allocation and blit yourself

Comment: @MarcGravell The 2d arrays are fixed within each version of the data file. The data structures themselves are very small, roughly a total of 60 float/boolean/ushort/unit elemets. I would rather not decode manually as then I'd have to write several new classes for each version up issue on the firmware.

Comment: well, "endianness" is a slight issue, but if we can ignore that: if you have a chunk of `byte`, again: `MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte,int>(theBytes).Slice(0,size).CopyTo(target);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236851/discussion-between-variablesquid-and-marc-gravell).

Comment: In the end, I've had to read in the data files directly. Not the cleanest solution, and doesn't help with future maintenance, but needed to move on...